# How to plot parallel trends for staggered diff-in-diff design?

Tags: data-visualization, econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference

I am using data from a controlled experiment with different timing of  treatment  implementation across individuals in the treated group. I can date treated observations with time distance to the implementation dates; However, how can I make a trend plot for control group? In particular, how to date the trend for control individuals?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the good way to do it is using "stacked cohort" diff-in-diff, where you create a dataset that covers a time window for each event, and then stack up the datasets into one. One example is in [Gormley and Matsa (2011)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/24/8/2781/1572102).

Comment: Actually, it is not correct to do this, because Post_t is not well-defined. We cannot test the parallel trend assumption in this case.